# Adjektive mit fest Präpositionen: Position der Präpositionalpronomen im Hauptsatz

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure

Regarding word order in main sentence/Haputsatz:

1. First adjective, then pronoun:
   Ich bin froh **darauf**, dass.. 
   Ich bin schuld **daran**, dass..
2. First pronoun, then adjective:
   Er ist **damit** beschäftigt,
   Es ist **davon** abhängig, dass..

What is the rule regarding word order here? When do we need to use order 1 vs order 2 ?

Comment: Just a side note: I'd say it's either _Ich bin **froh darüber**_ or _Ich **freue mich darauf**_ in your first example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both orders are possible and there is no hard rule for when one is preferred over the other.

Different adjectives might behave differently. A quick corpus search showed that:

> ist dafür zuständig dass **is more frequent than** ist zuständig dafür dass
>   ist schuld daran dass **is more frequent than** ist daran schuld dass

The view that the order of adjective plus dependant preposition is flexible is upheld by the observation that there are multiple possible topicalizations:

> Schuld daran bist du selber.
>   Daran schuld bist du selber.
>   Daran bist du selber schuld.
>   Schuld bist du selber daran.

Finally, note that although your question was about *Präpositionalpronomen*, prepositional phrases do not behave differently.